# how to schedule ge task queue to run only once

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, task-queue

Does anyone know how to schedule a Task queue in python for GAE, such that the task runs only once? I thought about using a cron, but a google search didn't turn up any configuration for running only once. I did however find 
[this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/111609/how-to-run-a-cron-job-only-once). Does anyone know how I can accomplish this in python for GAE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use [task_retry_limit](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/taskretryoptions#TaskRetryOptions_task_retry_limit).

```
taskqueue.Task(
        url='/process/url,
        params={'varname': 'value'},
        method='POST',
        retry_options=taskqueue.TaskRetryOptions(task_retry_limit=1)).add()
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I get it to run at a certain time in the future, but only once. Maybe it should be a cron instead if a task?

Comment: For the task to run at a certain time in the future, set the task eta, any time in the next 30 days - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks#Task_eta 
Note that cron would always be periodic.

Comment: I was searching a way to do this too, but in java. I found [TaskOptions#countdownMillis](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions#countdownMillis(long)) to be useful.